# How to migrate Magento 1 to Magento 2 using Migration script?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, data-migration-tool

I'm new to migrating the Magento 1 site to Magento 2 site. But the Magento 1 site has some custom data so client has shared us some of the migration script to migrate the data. But I'm not sure how to proceed with the migration with migration script. I have walk through some of the documents and all are suggesting using the data migration tool.

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: with the migration tool, you can able t migrate the magento default data only.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Yes got it. But how can we migrate the data using scripts? I have scripts but not sure where to start.

Comment: That depend on the script, what to do and how to do.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Is there any articles or document which i can refer?

Comment: See from where you got that script? at that place they mention those things how to use that one?

Comment: @Siv If possible can you please share link or script you have?